# Electron: Webview web notification click event

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have an Electron app loading WhatsApp Web from a webviewTag, on Windows 10.
Whenever new messages come through, a Windows notification comes up like you would normally get with WhatsApp Web (either in browser or the official desktop app).
When the notification is clicked, the message it came from within WhatsApp is opened, but the Electron BrowserWindow is not focused. So if anything is on top of my Electron app and the notification is clicked, it never comes to top/focus.

I've tried doing

```
// In renderer.js
if (webview.focus()) {
 ipcRenderer.send('webview-focused');
}
```

And

```
// In main.js
ipcMain.on('webview-focused', () => {
mainWindow.focus();
}
```

But nothing seems to change.

Comment: does the whatsapp icon at the bottom flash orange when you click the notification?

Comment: No it does not, because the webview within electron gets focus, but does not bring my app forward. It just stays behind whatever is on top of it.

Comment: rather than using `mainWindow.focus();` try using `mainWindow.show();` and tell me what happens

Comment: Nothing changes. What I'm also trying is to do, is to send an IPC message from webview to main (rather from renderer to main) on element focus. I can see the focus goes to the mainWindow, but it doesn't bring the window forward. Tried `mainWindow.focus()` and `mainWindow.show()`

Comment: try to hide the window using `mainWindow.hide` then show the window right after.

Comment: Is there no way to grab the notification click event? The notification comes from webview, so is there no way to get that notification event?